# How to group list childrens when parents is same

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm, entity-framework, linq

I have a list `Business` that looks this (`Company`: list parent; `Item`: list children)

```
Business
--------
CompanyA
    TaxRate
    Item1
        Name
        Price
        Total
    Item2
        Name
        Price
        Total
    Month
CompanyB
    TaxRate
    Item3
        Name
        Price
        Total
    Item4
        Name
        Price
        Total
    Month
CompanyA
    TaxRate
    Item5
        Name
        Price
        Total
    Item6
        Name
        Price
        Total
    Month
```

I want to group `Company` by `TaxRate` to that looks this

```
Business
--------
CompanyA
    TaxRate
    Item1
        Name
        Price
        Total
    Item2
        Name
        Price
        Total
    Item5
        Name
        Price
        Total
    Item6
        Name
        Price
        Total
    Month
CompanyB
    TaxRate
    Item3
        Name
        Price
        Total
    Item4
        Name
        Price
        Total
    Month
```

I hope someone will help me in this case

Comment: How is that "list" stored in your application? What should happen if the tax rates and/or month differ in the matching companies?

Comment: I need you to clarify how you store that list in your application - give details of the classes you use.

Comment: `TaxRate` in matching companies is not change, so I use it to make conditions for group by Company, `Month` can change

Comment: Dear PaulF, i just need algorithm or solution for this problem

Comment: If you need an answer to your question then you need to answer mine - how is your data stored. Is it in a database or a file? When you read that data in to your application how is it stored, what classes do you use? All of that is needed to give you an algorithm or solution.

Comment: Are you fetching your data in a JSON array, or in a C# list? Not clear how you are storing your data in which you can apply linq or groupby.

Comment: thanks, i will update question

Answer (score 1):

This is best way I found to accomplish task :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication45
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Business> companies = new List<Business>() {
                new Business() { name = "CompanyA",items = new List<Item>(){ new Item() { name = "Item1"}, new Item() { name = "Item2"}}},
                new Business() { name = "CompanyB", items = new List<Item>() { new Item() { name = "Item3"}, new Item() { name = "Item4"}}},
                new Business() { name = "CompanyA",items = new List<Item>(){ new Item() { name = "Item5"}, new Item() { name = "Item6"}}},
            };


            var groups = companies.GroupBy(x => x.name).Select(x => new { business = x.FirstOrDefault(), items = x.SelectMany(y => y.items) });
            List<Business> newCompanies = new List<Business>();
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                Business company = group.business;
                company.items = group.items.ToList();
                newCompanies.Add(company);
            }
        }

    }
    public class Business
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
        public decimal taxrate { get; set; }
        public string month { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string name { get;set;}
        public decimal price { get;set;}
        public decimal total { get;set;}
    }
}
```